# How to create string from string in php for loop with foreach

Tags: php, string

How I can create string (like I tried in modules_for) to get foreach from $g_module_1?

Current `echo` saying: _1 and _2

Should be: apple_1 and banana_2

```
  $g_module_1 = 'apple';
  $g_module_2 = 'banana';

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $modules_for = $g_module.'_'.$i;
    foreach ((array)$modules_for as $m_foreach_as) {
      echo $modules_for;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `$$` is what you'r searching for. [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: so in your case it would be `echo $$modules_for;`

Comment: @Jeff You're amazing. Thanks

Comment: needed another fix: `$modeules_for = 'g_module_'.$i;` - see https://3v4l.org/VG0Ia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

In your case it would be `echo $$modules_for;` - with another fix before: `$modules_for = 'g_module_'.$i;`

So the whole code would be

```
<?php

  $g_module_1 = 'apple';
  $g_module_2 = 'banana';

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $modules_for = 'g_module_'.$i;
    //foreach ((array)$modules_for as $m_foreach_as) {
      echo $$modules_for;
    //}
  }
```

I'm not sure what your intention with the foreach was, it doesn't really make sense here, so I commented it out..

A fiddle can be found here: https://3v4l.org/nsYq2

*Sidenote*: This looks like you could be better off with an array.